# Line integral calculation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

**Problem**

Let $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a $C^1$ function such that $f(-1)=0=f(1)$ and $f>0$ on $(-1,1)$. Knowing that the graph of $f$ is contained in the set $\{(x,y) : x^2+y^2\leq 1, y\geq 0 \}$. Calculate $$\int_C F.ds,$$

where $C$ is the curve of the graph of $f$ with a counterclockwise orientation and $$F(x,y)=(\dfrac{-y}{x^2+y^2}-2xy,\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}-x^2)$$

I know that if $\gamma$ is a scalar field with continuous gradient on an open connected set of $\mathbb R^n$, then for any two points $x,y$ joined by a piecewise regular path $\alpha$ the following identity holds $$\int_a^b \nabla \gamma d\alpha=\gamma(y)-\gamma(x)$$

So, if I could find a function $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $F=\nabla f$, then $\alpha:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ with $\alpha(t)=(t,f(t))$ is a parametrization of $C$ and, since I am under the hypothesis of the previous proposition (note that $\nabla f$ is continuous by the assumptions of the problem) the original integral is $$\int_C F.ds=\int_{-1}^1 (\nabla f(\alpha(t)).\alpha(t)'dt=f(1,0)-f(-1,0)$$

The problem is I can't find such $f$, I would appreciate suggestions to find a function of that form or an alternative solution to the problem (maybe it doesn't exist such $f$).

Answer (score 1):

The integrand is 
$$
\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}-2xydx-x^2dy=\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}-d(x^2y).
$$ 
To compute the first term, use polar coordinates: $x=r\cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\phi$. Then, by straightforward computation,
$$
\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}=d\phi,
$$
and so 
$$
\int_C F\cdot ds=(\phi-x^2y)|_{(-1,0)}^{(1,0)}=-\pi.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have some questions: I think that $f_n(x)=\dfrac{x}{n}$ works on $[-1,1]$. Why  the integral doesn't depend on $n$? For example, wouldn't the integral be $g(1,\dfrac{1}{n})-g(-1,\dfrac{-1}{n})$ over each $C_n$ ? My other two doubts are: you've said that the integral over the line segment $\{x \in [-1,1], y=0\}$ is zero, sorry if this is obvious but why is it $0$? The point $(0,0)$ is in that segment, but $\nabla g$ is not defined on $(0,0)$, so how can I integrate over the segment when the point $(0,0)$ is not defined for the integrand function?

Comment: 1) Your $f_n(x)$ does not work, because $f_n(-1)\ne0$ and $f_n(1)\ne0$. You should take $f_n$ satisfying the conditions you yourself stated for $f$.

Comment: 2) Well, you are right. I am editing my answer.